# Cannot access SQL Server CE DB after installation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have created a Winforms app that writes all data to a SQL Server CE database.  I am able to successfully install the app but when I try to read or write data, it tells me that it cannot open the connection. This only happens on PC's other than the one I created the program on. Nothing is hardcoded.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Pls share your connection string

Comment: Where are you putting the DB on the hard drive?  The connection string needs to match.

Comment: connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source= LaZSolutions.sdf";  The sdf is in the same folder as the executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows will fight you with permission issues for locating the database in the Program Files directory.  It doesn't belong there.

Consider moving the database to your own folder in this root folder:

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
```

Obviously, the connection string needs to reflect that folder path.

Comment: How would I do this? I understand I would need to change my connection string to "Data Source= Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData.LaZSolutions.sdf", but how do I setup everything around it?  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @user2379048 See [Create sql server compact file in appdata folder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7640142/719186)